# How can I use Stetho with RoomDataBase in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, stetho

I'am using RoomDatabase in my android studio project. And I want to inspect my database with Stetho. I already add it in my **build.gradle** file, but I don't know where to write the code `Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);`,  to begin inspection. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the code inside your main app file.

Also you can put it in any activity but if you want to get stetho globally i recommand to put it inside your app file.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating with Stetho is intended to be seamless and straightforward for most existing Android applications. There is a simple initialization step which occurs in your Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
  }
}
```

Also ensure that your MyApplication Java class is registered in your AndroidManifest.xml file, otherwise you will not see an "Inspect" button in chrome://inspect/#devices :

```
<manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        ...>
        <application
                android:name="MyApplication"
                ...>
         </application>
</manifest>
```

This brings up most of the default configuration but does not enable some additional hooks (most notably, network inspection). See [this](https://github.com/facebook/stetho#enable-network-inspection) for specific details on individual subsystems.